# Should I replace or refinish cupped hardwood flooring?

Tags: hardwood-floor, hardwood-refinishing

A few months ago, I had an insidious leak from an upstairs bathroom that caused cupping in the wood floors downstairs. It took a couple weeks to recognize and identify the leak, but once I did I repaired it and ensured no more water was coming through.

Now I have a section of wood, approximately 6'x10' that has moderate cupping (it has had several months to dry out). It is right next to the kitchen and included the board that acted as a transition from the tile to the wood. I pulled that board because it was too badly damaged to save and to ensure there was no mold growth underneath (there was none).

My question is whether it is easier to sand and refinish just that section, pull the damaged boards and replace them, or refinish the whole dining room area (which connects to the living room with no transition in flooring). I've found pre-finished flooring at Home Depot that closely matches the floor, though I'm a little concerned it will look much newer.

I'd rather not refinish the whole downstairs if possible. What's the best option?